# Retreive document data Firestore using React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My goal is to read a document in the Firebase Firestore database using React. I would like to get all the information within a certain document like the date of the last export. The only thing I was able to get back is a big confusing array. In this test, I tried to read if a certain activation code has already been used, and when it was used. My Firestore database has the following structure:

[Firestore database structure and document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d8ik.png)

When I execute the following code:

```
firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('Codes')
      .doc('00000')
      .get()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
```

[I get back the following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfbGp.png)

The only thing I was able to see is the document ID, and a confirmation that the document exists.
To communicate to the database, I used a library called React-firebase-js. If anyone can help me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might be missing the `.docs()` call

Comment: @Sxribe in the console.log after result within the then function? When doing that, I get a "TypeError: result.docs is not a function" error.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `.data()` as was written in the answer. I mixed the two up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('Codes')
      .doc('00000')
      .get()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data())
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

need to call result.data() as per the above documentation

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed it in the documentation, thanks for the clarification.